# QProcess - Destroyed while process is still running

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Необходимо запустить python скрипт упакованный в .exe файл.

```
void MessengerMatrix::sendMessage(QString roomId, int messageId)
{
    QProcess* bot_matrix = new QProcess(this);
    QString cur_path;
    QString bot_path;
    QString str_messageId;
    str_messageId = QString::number(messageId);
    QStringList listArg;
    listArg << roomId << str_messageId;
    cur_path = QDir::currentPath().replace('/',"\\");
    bot_path = cur_path + "\\messengers\\matrix\\matrix_bot.exe";
    bot_matrix->start(bot_path, listArg);
    bot_matrix->waitForFinished(-1);
}
```

Когда запускается matrix_bot.exe он порождает ещё один процесс matrix_bot.exe, который и должен отправить сообщение. И как только порождается дочерний - завершаются оба процесса не успев выполниться. Насколько я понял, проблема в замене ссылки дочерним процессом, как это описано [здесь](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qprocess-external-programs/). Возможно ли как-то исправить данную проблему, не прибегая к методу [startDetached()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1)?

Comment: а, вы уверены, что он запускается? попробуйте добавить `bot_matrix->setWorkingDirectory( )`, обрабатываете ли вы сигнал `errorOccurred`?

Comment: Действительно, добавил bot_matrix->setWorkingDirectory() и всё заработало. Pavel Gridin, огромное Вам спасибо. Не знаю как Вам плюсануть в карму